# ABAP debugger: How do i get to the start of execution of my program without using a breakpoint

Tags: abap

Whenever I run my program on a ABAP debugger -without setting a breakpoint- it starts executing the program from the SAP ABAP programs running under my program and I have to keep pressing F5/F6 to get to start of my code. This wastes my time.

How do I let ABAP debugger know I want to start right from the start of my own code, and I do not want to debug SAP code. 
[image: Screen showing SAP code being executed, I need to get to my program as a starting poing.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SE38 to start your ABAP-Program there you find a DEBUGGING-Button.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

- You might want to raise a SAPnet issue since this might be considered a bug in the processing of the statement `BREAK-POINT ... AT NEXT APPLICATION STATEMENT`
- You might want to take a look at [Layer Aware Debugging](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/64/e847c15efc48dfa3348fb54b8a6267/content.htm), which does come in handy for other situations as well.